# mod_rewrite to include a question mark in rewritten URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

Maybe I'm attempting to do something that isn't possible, or I'm missing something completely obvious.

What I want to do is rewrite the following:

```
^/report/user?(.*)$ ./report/user.php?userid=$1 [L,NC]
```

I have tried escaping the `?` using `/\?` however that throws and internal server error.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to get the query string, but the error might be something else. What is the rest of the instruction?

Comment: The only rewrite rule I have is that one, so whatever works with that :)

Comment: The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the URL-path, which excludes the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you might try:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule     ^/report/user$ ./report/user.php?userid=%1 [L,NC]
```

If your user IDs are alphanumeric, then just change the last part in the `RewriteCond` to `([0-9a-zA-Z]+)`

Comment: Ah, didn't even think to ask if only the userid was after the `?`. Makes more sense that way.

Comment: It's only my assumption, guessing from what the question's code looks like ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a `?` is regex for 1 or 0 times, so you are asking if `r` is there 1 or 0 times and grabbing everything else. If you want to capture the query string into another query (and not just transfer it) then try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?report/user$ /report/user.php?userid=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

... tested on a local machine `?a=1&b=2` -> `?userid=a=1&b=2` so probably not what you want

Unsure how that will turn out for the query string, but it should transfer it. Try it with `R` flag to see what it looks like. If you simply want to add to the query string you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?report/user$ /report/user.php?userid=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

.. tested on a local machine the query string `?a=1&b=2` -> `?userid=1&a=1&b=2`

Just changing the location without changing the query doesn't require QSA

```
RewriteRule ^/?report/user$ /report/user.php [L,NC]
```

.. tested on a local machine the query string `?a=1&b=2` -> `?a=1&b=2`

You can test rewrite here if you want http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ , just remember it rolls over once, so can just test basic stuff. I don't think the `QSA` (query string append) is programmed in either, but it's still a decent tool.